# How to show file download progress with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I've tried using the `FetchContent` module and `file(DOWNLOAD ...)` to download some dependencies for my project at build time. I'd rather use `FetchContent` only, but it creates so many files polluting the build dir that I'm willing to implement every step using the `file` command.

I managed to correctly download, check the file hash and extract it. But the download is blocking (as expected) and I get no output from it, so it's hard to check if anything went wrong or if Cmake is just downloading a big file. I'm using an HTTP URL. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
# Fetch file
if(NOT EXISTS "${EXTRACTED_DIR}")
    message("Downloading file...")
    file(DOWNLOAD "${FILE_URL}" "${DOWNLOADED_FILE}"
        SHOW_PROGRESS
        HTTPHEADER ${AUTH_HEADER}
        EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=${ARTIFACT_HASH}
        STATUS DOWNLOAD_RESULT)
    list(GET DOWNLOAD_RESULT 0 DOWNLOAD_RESULT_CODE)
    if(NOT DOWNLOAD_RESULT_CODE EQUAL 0)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed downloading! Error: ${DOWNLOAD_RESULT}.")
    endif()
    message("Extracting file ${DOWNLOADED_FILE}...")
    execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E tar xv "${DOWNLOADED_FILE}"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${EXTRACTED_DIR}/"
        OUTPUT_QUIET)
endif()
include_directories("${EXTRACTED_DIR}/include")
```

Even using `SHOW_PROGRESS` on the `file(DOWNLOAD ...)`, I see no output. I was expecting something like what `wget` provides. Is that normal behavior? What can I do to present download rate, ETA, etc, some feedback to the user?

Comment: Are you testing this in a Windows or Unix environment?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: Did you try `Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)`? I didn't need to set anything else to have a donwload indicator.

Comment: I'm using that in other flows successfully. Honestly, I don't even remember the solution, probably `FETCHCONTENT_QUIET` was the culprit here.

Comment: @bw0248, add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just did, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and could resolve it with simply setting `Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)`.
I did not have to set any other properties to have a download indicator showing.